# jQuery event returns multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

In script.js I have:

```
$('body').on('click','.element', function(){
    var myID=$(this).attr('id');
    $.get('../controller/querydata/'+myID, function(response){
        console.log(response)
    }).done(function(){
                 alert('it works');
    })
})
```

.element comes from another ajax call and sometimes are more than one, hence each one has a unique id, but response from controller and alert from .done callback are excecuted multiple times. having .off().on() seems to work, but after it gets called disables functionality on other elements.

Comment: the code you have will fire once per click. the symptoms you are describing don't match the code.

Comment: Are you running the script multiple times?

Comment: @KevinB that's why I asked, to me seems to be fine

Comment: @deadPoet the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @freedomn-m no, just once. I call other functions from script.js and they are all ok, but the only one calling a event based on an ajax element is this one.

Comment: @KevinB I'm using web2py and in controller.py code for querydata is basic.
    def querydata():
        db(db.table.id==request.args(0)).update(field=False)
    return None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem,it was me. I called the script.js in another file without noticing as @freedomm-m suspected, after an extensive search inside the project folders fount it.